# EOutOfResources exception when trying to restore tray icon

Tags: delphi-xe, trayicon

I'm getting an EOutOfResources exception 'Cannot remove shell notification icon' when trying to implement code to restore the tray icon after an Explorer crash/restart. My code is based on the old solution found [here](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/66/477545.html). The exception occurs when trying to hide the trayicon. Why does the Delphi XE code below not work?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ImgList, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TrayIcon1: TTrayIcon;
    ImageListTray: TImageList;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); Override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  msgTaskbarRestart : Cardinal; {custom systemwide message}  

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

//ensure systray icon recreated on explorer crash
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  msgTaskbarRestart := RegisterWindowMessage('TaskbarCreated');
end;

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if (msgTaskbarRestart <> 0) and (Message.Msg = msgTaskbarRestart) then begin 
    TrayIcon1.Visible := False; {Destroy the systray icon here}//EOutOfResources exception here
    TrayIcon1.Visible := True;  {Replace the systray icon}
    Message.Result := 1;
  end;
  inherited WndProc(Message);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TTrayIcon.Visible` property setter raises `EOutOfResources` when a `NIM_DELETE` request fails:

```pascal
procedure TCustomTrayIcon.SetVisible(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FVisible <> Value then
  begin
    FVisible := Value;
    ...

    if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    begin
      if FVisible then
        ...
      else if not (csLoading in ComponentState) then
      begin
        if not Refresh(NIM_DELETE) then
          raise EOutOfResources.Create(STrayIconRemoveError); // <-- HERE
      end;
      ...
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Where `Refresh()` is just a call to the Win32 `Shell_NotifyIcon()` function:

```pascal
function TCustomTrayIcon.Refresh(Message: Integer): Boolean;
  ...
begin
  Result := Shell_NotifyIcon(Message, FData);
  ...
end;
```

When you receive the `TaskbarCreated` message, your previous icons are no longer present in the Taskbar, so `Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE)` returns False.  When the Taskbar is (re-)created, you are not supposed to try to remove old icons at all, only re-add new icons with `Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD)` as needed.

`TTrayIcon` has a public `Refresh()` method, but that uses `NIM_MODIFY` instead of `NIM_ADD`, so that will not work in this situation, either:

```pascal
procedure TCustomTrayIcon.Refresh;
begin
  if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
  begin
    ...
    if Visible then
      Refresh(NIM_MODIFY);
  end;
end;
```

However, you don't actually need to handle the `TaskbarCreated` message manually when using `TTrayIcon`, because it already handles that message internally for you, and it will call `Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD)` if `Visible=True`:

```pascal
procedure TCustomTrayIcon.WindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
  ...
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    ...
  else
    if (Cardinal(Message.Msg) = RM_TaskBarCreated) and Visible then
      Refresh(NIM_ADD); // <-- HERE
  end;
end;

...

initialization
  ...
  TCustomTrayIcon.RM_TaskBarCreated := RegisterWindowMessage('TaskbarCreated');
end.
```

If, for some reason, that is not working correctly, and/or you need to handle `TaskbarCreated` manually, then I would suggest calling the protected `TCustomTrayIcon.Refresh()` method directly, eg:

```pascal
type
  TTrayIconAccess = class(TTrayIcon)
  end;

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if (msgTaskbarRestart <> 0) and (Message.Msg = msgTaskbarRestart) then begin 
    if TrayIcon1.Visible then begin
      // TrayIcon1.Refresh;
      TTrayIconAccess(TrayIcon1).Refresh(NIM_ADD);
    end;
    Message.Result := 1;
  end;
  inherited WndProc(Message);
end;
```

Otherwise, simply don't use `TTrayIcon` at all.  It is known to be buggy.  I have seen a lot of people have a lot of problems with `TTrayIcon` over the years.  I would suggest using `Shell_NotifyIcon()` directly instead.  I have never had any problems using it myself.